# How display selected item from Bootstrap 4 drop-down item menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display what the user selects once they click on an item from the Boostrap 4 drop down menu.

Ex. "What is your eye color" User selects : Blue - Blue is displayed after click.

Ex. "What is your skin tone" User selects: Fair- Fair is displayed after click.

I have done research and jQuery seems to be the best bet however all of the solutions are for older bootstrap versions. I'm using Boostrap 4 and there are no li tags in the bootstrap 4 code, it's all a class tags so I'm not sure how to fit that into the jQuery option below. Also, I have (2) dropdown menus - please see pic. I'm not sure if this makes it more tricky. Any assistance or direction would be great.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready (function(){

$('#selectmenu1 a').click(function){

}
```

HTML:

```
 <!--Drop down Item 1 -->
<h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">What is your eye color</h3>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
    Eye Color
  </button>


  <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu1" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="brown"><img src="img/brown_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle"> Brown</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="blue"><img src="img/blue_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Blue</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="green"><img src="img/green_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Green</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="hazel"><img src="img/hazel_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Hazel</a>
  </div>

</div>


<!--Drop down Item 2-->
<h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> What is your skin tone</h3>
<div id="menu2" class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
    Skin Tone
  </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu2" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="fair"><img src="img/fair.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Fair (porcelain)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="light"><img src="img/light.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Light (fair to light)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="medium"><img src="img/medium.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Medium (light to medium)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="bronze"><img src="img/bronze_dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Bronze dark (deep tan)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="tan"><img src="img/tan.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Tan (warm to medium)</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="rich"><img src="img/dark.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Rich (deep)</a>
  </div>

</div>

<script>

    document.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
          initApplication();
      }
  }


  var eyeColor = null;
  function selectMenu1(value){
    eyeColor = value;
  }

  var skinTone = null;
  function selectMenu2(value){
    skinTone = value;
  }

  function validate()  { 
    if (eyeColor && skinTone){
      // alert(`You selected ${eyeColor} eye colour and ${skinTone} skin tone.`);

    if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="fair"){
      window.location = "brown/brown_fair.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="light"){
      window.location = "brown/brown_light.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="medium"){
      window.location = "brown/brown_medium.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="bronze"){
      window.location = "brown/brown_bronze.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="tan"){
      window.location = "brown/brown_tan.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="rich"){
      window.location = "brown/brown_rich.html";
    }   

    if (eyeColor=="blue" && skinTone=="fair"){
      window.location = "blue/blue_fair.html";
    } else if (eyeColor =="blue" && skinTone=="light"){
      window.location = "blue/blue_light.html";
    } else if (eyeColor =="blue" && skinTone=="medium"){
      window.location = "blue/blue_medium.html";
    } else if (eyeColor =="blue" && skinTone=="bronze"){
      window.location = "blue/blue_bronze.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="blue" && skinTone=="tan"){
      window.location = "blue/blue_tan.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="blue" && skinTone=="rich"){
      window.location = "blue/blue_rich.html";
    }

    if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="fair"){
        window.location = "green/green_fair.html";
    } else if (eyeColor == "green" && skinTone=="light"){
      window.location= "green/green_light.html";
    } else if (eyeColor== "green" && skinTone=="medium"){
      window.location="green/green_medium.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="bronze"){
      window.location="green/green_bronze.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="tan"){
      window.location="green/green_tan.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="green" && skinTone=="rich"){
      window.location="green/green_rich.html";
    }


    if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="fair"){
        window.location = "hazel/hazel_fair.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="light"){
      window.location="hazel/hazel_light.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="medium"){
      window.location="hazel/hazel_medium.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="bronze"){
      window.location="hazel/hazel_bronze.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="tan"){
      window.location="hazel/hazel_tan.html";
    } else if (eyeColor=="hazel" && skinTone=="rich"){
      window.location="hazel/hazel_rich.html";
    }
  }

    else if (!eyeColor){
      alert("Please pick an eye colour");
    } else if (!skinTone){
      alert("Please pick a skin tone");
    }
    }

  function initApplication(){
    //setup dropdown menu selection events
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu")).forEach((menu,idx)=>{
      const menuCallbackName = menu.attributes.onchange.value;
      const fetchedCallback = window[menuCallbackName] || null;

      if (fetchedCallback){
        Array.from(menu.children).forEach((child)=>{
          const callbackValue = child.attributes.data ? child.attributes.data.value : null;
          if (callbackValue) child.onclick = () => fetchedCallback(callbackValue);
        });
      } else console.error(`No callback function named ${menuCallbackName} for menu ${idx}`);

    });
  }
</script>
```

[image: Ref photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

I included input-group into my html, as well as included jQuery:

HTML:

```
    <h3 class="display-4" style="font-size: 1.5rem;">What is your eye color</h3>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <div class="input-group justify-content-center">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="background-color: #588c7e;">
                    Eye Color

                </button>

                <div class="dropdown-menu" onchange="selectMenu1" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="brown" ><img src="img/brown_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle"> Brown</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="blue" ><img src="img/blue_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Blue</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="green" ><img src="img/green_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Green</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data="hazel" ><img src="img/hazel_eye.jpg" class="rounded-circle" > Hazel</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<script>
    $(".dropdown-menu a ").click(function(){
                $(this).parents(".input-group-btn").find('.btn').text($(this).text());
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

And if even easier

```
<script>
$(".dropdown-menu a ").click(function () {
    let x = $(this).text();
    alert(x);
});
</script>
```

Works with this HTML below. No input-group needed and jQuery short enough.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Navbar</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
id="dropdownMenuButton" style="width:4rem"
            data-toggle="dropdown">en
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropDownMenu" aria- 
    labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">en</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">de</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of how this answers the question. Thanks! ([How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer))

Answer (score 1):

You can access the data using jQuery's "attr()" function.

```
$('#selectmenu1 a').click(
  function( event ){
    // Prevents browser from treating like normal anchor tag
    event.preventDefault()

    // Retrieves data in anchor tag
    let data = $(this).attr('data')
  }
)
```

Side note, [it is possible](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/) to use list tags for this in Bootstrap. Bootstrap is really flexible and robust. Also, in my opinion, it would be most semantically correct to use "select".

Comment: Hi arborvitae, I went ahead and tried the code you listed and it doesn't work.

Comment: Mind giving me an example of how you used it? my snippet retrieves the data and stores it as a variable, but it doesn't do anything with it after that.

Comment: I went ahead and added my JS for viewing.